# How to configure express-session with default variables

Tags: javascript, express, express-session

By default express-session gives us an empty session object on every request. Is there any way to configure the middleware with some default variables instead? For example lets say we want to have a user object inside the req.session, which would look like this:

```
var user = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  username: "guest"
}
```

What I use currently to solve this is:

```
app.use(expressSession({ 
  secret: "cats", 
  saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something is stored
  resave: false, //don't save session if unmodified
  store: store, 
  cookie: {
  maxAge: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // In milliseconds. 5 Days in total.
  httpOnly: true
}, 
}), (req, res, next) => {
 // Initialise default variables on the session object
 if (typeof req.session.initialisedSession === "undefined") {
  req.session.initialisedSession = true,
  req.session.user = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    username: "guest"
  }
 }
 next();
});
```

However, is there any other way. For example configuring the express-session middleware somehow?